# C# Pass a type into method to be evaluated in an "is" statement?

Tags: c#, interface, types

I want to do something like the code listed below.  Basically, I want to be able to create an object but at the same time optionally put on an interface requirement

```
public UserControl CreateObject(string objectName, Type InterfaceRequirement)
{
     ///// create object code abbreviated here
     UserControl NewControl = createcontrol(objectName);

     if (InterfaceRequirement == null || NewControl is InterfaceRequirement)
          return NewControl;
     else
          throw new SystemException("Requested object does not implement required interface");

}
```

The above code does not compile due to issues with InterfaceRequirement

now, I know i can do this with generics:

```
public UserControl CreateObject<T>(string objectName)
{
    ///// create object code abbreviated here
     UserControl NewControl = createcontrol(objectName);

     if (NewControl is T)
          return NewControl;
     else
          throw new SystemException("Requested object does not implement required interface");
}
```

but with the generics, the interface requirement is not optional.  The first code example where I am passing type as a parameter does not compile and I cant see to get the syntax right.  Does anyone know a way to do this without generics so i can make it optional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check `typeof(InterfaceRequirement).IsAssignableFrom(theType)` ?

Otherwise, maybe `theType.GetInterfaces()` and look  for it.

(where `Type theType = NewControl.GetType();`)

Comment: You were right with a little adjustment to your code:  InterfaceRequirement.IsAssignableFrom(NewControl.GetType());

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a constraint for T:

```
public UserControl CreateObject<T>(string objectName) where T : class
{
    ///// create object code abbreviated here
     UserControl NewControl = createcontrol(objectName);

     if (NewControl is T)
          return NewControl;
     else
          throw new SystemException("Requested object does not implement required interface");
}
```

hth Mario

Comment: The generic one works fine and in this case its really to enforce sub interfaces for a factory creation if it needs to but this is optional so generics arent really the way to go unless i want a generic and non generic method